# Can't skip login in Qt installer?

Tags: qt

In the past, I have been able to use the Qt installers & maintenance tool without a login by agreeing to GPL licensing and pressing the skip button. But today I discovered that skip button is no longer appearing.

Searching for this issue has so far only turned up references to the [2015 controversy which ended when the project committed to not requiring a login](https://www.qt.io/blog/2015/05/06/changing-qt-account-to-be-optional-in-the-online-installer).

I assume that if Qt project had intentionally gone back on this, it would have made some kind of news.

How can I continue to use the Qt installer without a Qt account?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

This has broken the CI for a project I work on so I spent yesterday looking around. Have a read (and leave a complaint) of this blog post: https://www.qt.io/blog/qt-offering-changes-2020

- For the online installer you are out of luck.
- For the offline installer I got it to work but it seems like you have to prevent the installer application from phoning home for the "Skip" button to show up.

Comment: You can prevent the installer from phoning home by setting 0.0.0.0:123 as a proxy

Comment: For more context - see what happened 5 years ago: https://www.qt.io/blog/2015/05/06/changing-qt-account-to-be-optional-in-the-online-installer

Answer (score 0):

You could use the **old** "qt-unified-online-installer", where you still could
skip the login, to install a **newer** Qt version!
The latest installer version, where this is possible (as far as I know) is the version 2.0.5-2.

The old installer for Linux can still be downloaded from here:

https://download.qt.io/archive/online_installers/2.0/

Unfortunately, Qt.io, in their wisdom, decided to remove the Windows and MacOS online installers from their download mirrors, but at least a slightly older version for Windows can still be found via Google, search for "qt-unified-windows-x86-2.0.2-online.exe".
Here's a link for direct download that I've found (06/2023), but I didn't test it on Windows!

https://qt-creator.software.informer.com/download/?caeae88

If anybody knows where to get the old 2.0 MacOS online installer, please let me know...

### Example for Linux:

Now run the installer, skip the login, and when you are on the "Welcome" page, press "Settings" and go to the "Repositories" tab.
Disable all "Default repositories" and select "User defined repositories"
(must be selected!!).
Then press the "Add" button to add your own Qt repositories, depending
on what version you want to install, e.g. for Qt 5.15.2 on Linux, add these
five Linux repositories:

```
https://download.qt.io/online/qtsdkrepository/linux_x64/desktop/qt5_5152
https://download.qt.io/online/qtsdkrepository/linux_x64/desktop/qt5_5152_src_doc_examples
https://download.qt.io/online/qtsdkrepository/linux_x64/desktop/tools_generic
https://download.qt.io/online/qtsdkrepository/linux_x64/desktop/tools_qtcreator
https://download.qt.io/online/qtsdkrepository/linux_x64/desktop/licenses
```

Then press "OK", repeat skipping the login page and press "Next", now the installer should load all data needed to install the newer Qt version, and you are able to select what package you want to install. :-)

### Other versions and systems:

(or: how to get those repositories URLs)

If you want to install another Qt version, and/or a version for ***your*** OS, just look up here:

https://download.qt.io/online/qtsdkrepository/

... select the folder with your OS, and go into the "desktop" subfolder!

In here, search for the folder pair that has your wanted version (e.g. Qt 5.12.11 = "qt5_51211" and "qt5_51211_src_doc_examples"), and replace the first two repository URLs from the example above with those two (right click > copy link).
Then search for the corresponding folders/links of the other three needed repositories of your OS ("tools_generic", "tools_qtcreator" and "licenses").

*Tested this on Debian Linux 12 x64, with latest Qt5 and Qt6 repositories.*

Have fun! :-D